# Группировка вывода дочерних разделов в родительские Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеются города `city`, автомойки `wash` и посты на них `bfrs`.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c97795

Как вывести список с группировкой постов по городам и автомойкам, типа:

```
Paris:

  «Monmartre»

   1. BFR-5

  «Mouline Rouge»
 
   1. BFR-11
   2. BFR-201

Bogota....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN wash_addr IS NULL THEN city_name
            WHEN bfrs_name IS NULL THEN CONCAT('-',wash_addr)
            ELSE                        CONCAT('--',bfrs_name)
            END name
FROM ( SELECT city.name city_name, null wash_addr, null bfrs_name
       FROM city
     UNION ALL
       SELECT city.name, wash.addr, null
       FROM city
       JOIN wash ON city.pref = wash.city
     UNION ALL
       SELECT city.name, wash.addr, bfrs.name
       FROM city
       JOIN wash ON city.pref = wash.city
       JOIN bfrs ON city.pref = bfrs.city AND wash.id = bfrs.wash
     ) subquery
ORDER BY city_name, wash_addr IS NOT NULL, wash_addr, bfrs_name IS NOT NULL, bfrs_name;
```

> если в каком-то городе нет мойки (или постов) его не выводить. – kilotonna

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN wash_addr IS NULL THEN city_name
            WHEN bfrs_name IS NULL THEN CONCAT('-',wash_addr)
            ELSE                        CONCAT('--',bfrs_name)
            END name
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT city.name city_name, null wash_addr, null bfrs_name
       FROM city
       JOIN wash ON city.pref = wash.city
       JOIN bfrs ON city.pref = bfrs.city AND wash.id = bfrs.wash
     UNION ALL
       SELECT DISTINCT city.name, wash.addr, null
       FROM city
       JOIN wash ON city.pref = wash.city
       JOIN bfrs ON city.pref = bfrs.city AND wash.id = bfrs.wash
     UNION ALL
       SELECT city.name, wash.addr, bfrs.name
       FROM city
       JOIN wash ON city.pref = wash.city
       JOIN bfrs ON city.pref = bfrs.city AND wash.id = bfrs.wash
     ) subquery
ORDER BY city_name, wash_addr IS NOT NULL, wash_addr, bfrs_name IS NOT NULL, bfrs_name;
```

Comment: Спасибо. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60fe0c/1 У меня акцент на отображение именно данных таблицы bfrs. То есть, если в каком-то городе нет мойки (или постов) его не выводить.

Comment: Вот и все, что смог "родить" за ночь: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60fe0c/3 - но нет группировки по городам и мойкам, как у Вас.

Comment: @kilotonna *если в каком-то городе нет мойки (или постов) его не выводить* А сразу сказать об этом было, конечно, никак нельзя... Вы подумайте и, если есть ещё какие-то условия и требования, давайте их сразу все. Да, поскольку это важная информация - внесите её в текст вопроса. Вариант по текущим требованиям - добавлен.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Буду разбираться. Насчет доп. условий - мне пока трудновато формулировать мысль. Спасибо еще раз!